# How to grab block of text using regular expression (PowerShell/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, powershell

```
resource "aws_instance" "launch-ec2-servers"
{
    ami = "${var.ec2_ami}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    key_name = "${var.key_name}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group}"]
    subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
    count= "${var.count}"

    root_block_device
    {
        volume_size = "${var.root_volume_size}"
        volume_type = "${var.root_volume_type}"
    }

    ebs_block_device
    {
        device_name = "${var.ebs_device_name}"
        snapshot_id = "${var.ebs_snapshot_id}"
        volume_type = "${var.ebs_volume_type}"
    }

    tags
    {
        Name = "${var.app_name}"
    }
}
```

Hey,

I am trying to grab the **ebs_block_device** block section with regular expression in C#/PowerShell/ASP.Net.

So far, I tried this as my regular expression:
(ebs_block_device)(?s)(.[^}]+.)

The block section I'm interested in from the code is:

```
 ebs_block_device
    {
       device_name = "${var.ebs_device_name}"
       snapshot_id = "${var.ebs_snapshot_id}"
       volume_type = "${var.ebs_volume_type}"
    }
```

Can you help me to grab that block of text in between the curly brackets correctly?

Comment: Why not parse it as JSON instead?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(ebs_block_device)(\s+)(\{[\s\S]*?\}(?!"))
```